# Getting wrong display when i add www to my domain name

Tags: html, css

Whenever i add "WWW" to a page on my website, it erases some of the css of that page. but if i load the page without adding the "WWW." prefix it displays properly. Pls help

Comment: If you are only using HTML and CSS, and you are using `<link>` tag to link the css files, then bear in mind that you should have the base url having the same origin(i.e. same domain). Probably you are not.

Comment: Okay thanks. 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="viewLodge.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="viewLodge1.css">

This is how i make the link to the css file

Comment: If you have `www.domain.com` and your base URL in `<base>` tag is `domain.com`, then css may not be loaded

Comment: I just checked and it turns out that loading www.mydomain.com/mycss.css gives a different version from mydomain.com/mycss.css

I updated some class names on the page as well as the css file, but it doesn't reflect on the "www" version

Comment: It was a timing thing i guess. For some reason, It takes some time for changes to take effect on both versions. Although I stay open to corrections. Thanks @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy

Comment: If you use PHP, you could use `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` to get your hostname. Since you are using third-party domain, using PHP would be 99% possible, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect your site to to go the non www.-site, with this redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you add that code to your `.htaccess` people will get redirected to http://yourdomain.com when they enter http://www.yourdomain.com

Comment: Thanks. I though of this, but i have the website registered on third party websites with the "www." therefore, if i redirect users access to the "no-www." version, more problems.